# Which parts in NodeJs are asynchronous and which parts are not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Although I'm not having a practical problem, I'm in need of some explanation about what makes something asynchronous in standard Javascript  in NodeJs. Take for example this piece of code:

```
function pause(ms) {
    var dt = new Date()
    while((new Date()) - dt <= ms) {

    }
    console.log("Third")
}

console.log("First")

pause(3000)

console.log("second")
```

The output is

```
 First
 Third
 second
```

Since NodeJs is asynchronous I would have expected the outcome to be "First Second Third". The following code however is asynchronous:

```
console.log("First")
setTimeOut(function(){
    console.log("Third")
}, 3000)

console.log("Second")
```

The output is:
    First
    Second
    Third

The problem is I do not fully understand why. Is it because while loops are blocking, even though I've put it inside a function? If so, what else is blocking and what isn't? Has it something to do with the event loop? Are only I/O operations asynchronous? Is there an overview of what is and isn't or is there a general principle?

Comment: Generally it's IO and system operations like accessing the file system. There are thousands of Node APIs so in general the question is far too broad.

Comment: This is rather related to javascript. And there generally everything with callbacks and promises is async.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The question is related to basic Javascript in NodeJs. I did not intend to include all third party or native APIs. Is there even something that's asynchronous in vanilla Javascript?

Comment: So don't assume that just because your original pause() function takes awhile to finish that it is asynchronous.  It isn't, it just takes it a while to finish.  But it does not involve a callback, like setTimeOut(function(),...) which is handled differently -  look at event loops and callback functions.

Comment: exactly, that is what I mean. I did notice that is not handled asynchronous, but why does node not recognize the pause function takes a while and tries to execute the last console log in the mean time?

Comment: @Piepongwong because it can't. The function isn't added to the callback queue, it is instead executed immediately and can't continue until it returns. The only way a callback can be delayed and executed later is if it is added to the callback queue, such as by using setTimeout or setImmediate.

Answer (score 0):

The JS/Node.js language by default is synchronous (or blocking if you prefer) **- as are most programming languages -** in that lines of code are executed one after another, which is why the output of the first example is "First", "Third", "Second".

```
console.log("First");  // Outputs "First"

pause(3000);           // Outputs "Third"

console.log("second"); // Outputs "Second"
```

That is pause() is just a function that is called and executed synchronously; there is nothing special about it.

In the second example the languages event-driven model has been used via setTimeout(), which accepts a callback function as a parameter that is called when the timer expires. Which means the sequence of outputs is different.

So to answer your question: standard JavaScript code is synchronous, but many of the standard library functions are non-blocking. As indeed your own can be if written accordingly.

Which standard library functions? Well I/O and timers generally are non-blocking, but it really is a case of reading the documentation.